# Facebook sharer not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to set up facebook sharing.  But i'm having problem getting any information to show other than the link.

This is the rendered head:

```
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta content='prettySocial - custom social share buttons.' property='og:title'>
    <meta content='http://sonnyt.com/prettySocial/' property='og:url'>
    <meta content='http://sonnyt.com/assets/imgs/prettySocial.png' property='og:image'>
    <meta content='Custom share buttons for Pinterest, Twitter, Facebook and Google Plus.' property='og:description'>
```

This is where the button is clicked

```
<a class='prettySocial fa fa-facebook' data-description="this isn't changing" data-type='facebook' data-url='http://mysite-staging.dev/orders/1' href='#'></a>
```

and an image of what I see

[image]

But the link is set to the correct path. "http://mysite-staging.dev/orders/1"

Comment: Load your URL on this link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to see what the webpage is read as via facebook. This can help you debuger

Comment: It's probably because your link is not public (it's a staging environment right?) so facebook can't read anything. Try it on a public environment